# Зачем нужны суффиксы числовых литералов?

Tags: c++, c

Предположим, я хочу инициализировать переменную:

```
float f = 1.0f;
```

Бесит меня здесь только `f`

Я понимаю, что изначально 1.0 предполагается как число типа `double`, но какая разница, если `1.0`  все равно вписывается в `float`? Зачем нужны эти суффиксы, если без них все прекрасно работает? Разве не компилятор преобразовывает типы за меня?

Comment: По жизни, не нужно, можете не писать `f`

Comment: лучше писать с литералом f

Comment: @avp, Я начал изучать c++ по книге прата и в каждом примере он советует использовать какие-то суффиксы, например, вместе с `char16_t` использовать `u`(unsigned int), и так в каждом примере. Я в Си никогда их не использовал и не понимал зачем это надо, но прата будто настаивает чтобы я это делал

Comment: Ты меняешь тип литерала. Зачем же еще? `"string"` и `u8"string"` - два разных типа, первый - `const char*`, второй `const char8_t*`. А есть еще *string literals* и *chrono literals*, а также *user-defined literals* (они должны начинаться с `_`).

Comment: И там разница уже совсем очевидна: `std::chrono::milliseconds{700}` против `700ms`.

Comment: Есть неявный каст типов, есть явный. Ты должен знать как это работает. В арифметических операциях, операциях присваивания, при передаче в функцию, etc. может что-то неявно скаститься, если это позволено. Сишный каст (явный) фактически кастит что угодно во что угодно. Плюсовые касты имеют ограничения, и постараются непозволить тебе сделать глупость.

Comment: Понятно что меняю , но я не понимал зачем это нужно, я думал что работу по преобразованиям выполняет компилятор в большинстве случаев, ответ `wololo` все разъяснил, плюс немного разобрался по каким правилам c++ преобразовывает типы, и все стало гораздо понятнее. Когда прогал на сишке не думал что там под капотом...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Суффиксы нужны, чтобы явно указать тип литерала. Так как вещественное число `1` представимо точно типом `float`, то способ, которым вы его зададите не принципиален, результат будет одинаков:

```
float f1 = 1.0L;
float f2 = 1.0;
float f3 = 1.0f;
float f4 = 1;
float f5 = 1ULL;
float f6 = (char)1;
float f7 = true;
```

Но бывают и ситуации немного сложнее, где тип литерала напрямую влияет на конечный [результат](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b4039b065f26eb6):

```
cout << std::sin(1.0 ) << endl; //8.41470984807896505e-01
cout << std::sin(1.0f) << endl; //8.41470956802368164e-01

float f = 0.1;
cout << (f == 0.1 ) << endl; //false
cout << (f == 0.1f) << endl; //true
    
long long ll_1 = 65535   * 65535; //(Для 32-битного int тут UB)
long long ll_2 = 65535LL * 65535LL;
cout << ll_1 << endl; //-131071
cout << ll_2 << endl; //4294836225
```

Answer (score 4):

Литералы позволяют задавать тип литералу или (для пользовательских литералов) производить какие-то его преобразования.

Например:

```
// инициализация:
unsigned long long value{35};
auto value{35llu};

// вызываем вторую перегрузку
void foo(int x);
void foo(unsigned long long x);

foo(static_cast< unsigned long long >(35));
foo(35llu);
```

Answer (score 2):

И мое дополнение:

```
auto d = 1.0;
auto f = 1.0f;
```

Как вы понимаете, `d` будет иметь тип `double`, а `f` - тип `float`.